# How to load and instantiate at runtime an object from a different project?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Let's say I have an NSObject subclass named `Drawable` that implements

`-(NSImage *) representation`

Now, using another (running) program, I would like to create instances of Drawable. I'm working on the souce code of `Drawable`, so the object file for Drawable (.o) is not fixed.

Is there an architecture that would allow me to locate the object file for Drawable, load it, and create instances of Drawable, at runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a language/runtime that requires compiling and linking, you are describing a dynamic library or framework.  As you develop `Drawable`, build new versions of the dynamic library that packages it and the dynamic linker can take care of it.